# styled maps with Subgurim Google Maps

Tags: subgurim-maps

It is possible to create a styled map with Subgurim Google Map control?

Here the code in according to Google Api V3.

```
var styles = [{
featureType: "all",
elementType: "all",
stylers: [
{ saturation: -100 }
]
}];

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

var mapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType(styles);

map.mapTypes.set("mymap", mapType);

map.setMapTypeId("mymap");
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm one of the developers of Subgurim Maps and this feature will be available in our next version, hopefully before the end of the month. As soon as we have it I'll inform you through this question.